# Official React native documentation website

Tags: macos, facebook, react-native, github-pages

I have a problem connecting to the official documentation website of React Native. I have tried connecting to [the site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) with the latest version of Chrome (63.0.3239.132), Safari (Version 11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3)) & Firefox (57.0.4 (64-bit)). Also tried to load the website from my iPhone 7 but without success.

The error I get is the one below.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> facebook.github.io took too long to respond.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are you having this issue only on this page or is it a general issue? Try `ping facebook.github.io` (use `ctrl+c`  to stop it) and add the output to your question

Answer (score 0):

I think it's server error that not response to my web client, you could watch the network tab in Developer tool, for me, I get a pending request for a css file below.

solarized-dark.min.css:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/solarized-dark.min.css

This css file spend me almost 2 minutes to download!
Once you download this you cached, but the first time is very slow for me, btw I am Chinese developer visiting this site via VPN, you should be faster than me!